# yii2 cuts css classes in the emails

Tags: html, css, email, yii2, swiftmailer

I send email using template :

```
         $content='Message';
         Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/templates/templ', ['content'=>$content])
        ->setFrom('gorobets.asya@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('nastya.g2410@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('Message subject')
        ->send();
```

And my template :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?=   Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .footer {
         color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?= $content ?>
<div class="footer">With kind regards </div>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

When I read my email I can see that css classes doesn't work.  Class 'footer' also.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an Yii 2 issue. Most email clients ignore css styles if not applied directly to the element.

There is great article about that - [Using CSS in HTML Emails: The Real Story](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)